# Downloading IMAP/POP3 emails on a remote server to a local mail server

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, pop3, imapsync

I need to setup a local server that will download email (IMAP or POP3) from remoteserver e.g gmail or webmail, to a local server. Such that users can have structured access (either via mail client or web clients like Roundcube) to that download email content on the local server.
The aim is to:

1. Have a backup server for the remote email server
2. Take some email permanently off the remote server
3. Allow some users to access emails only on the local server.

- Pls note that the removeserver is currently a shared hosting server.
- The localserver doesn't have dedicated static IP, but have access internet.

4. All users should also be able to use SMTP as outgoing email.

Your advise is much appreciated in advance.

Thank you

Comment: Things get slightly less messy if you use the *sync* features shipped by your IMAP server (usually you would chose *dovecot*). That is about as much advice as you can get until you have a detailed plan and an actual *question* or *problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged imapsync, let's consider this option:

> Have a backup server for the remote email server

That's the basic of imapsync job.

> Take some email permanently off the remote server

Use options `--search` to select the messages and `--delete1` to remove them from the imap source server.

The other questions are not related to imapsync and are very dependent of your context. They might reflect a lack of knowledge about email stuff and internet but that's not a real problem. Explain your need and your context, maybe we'll fulfill your issue.

Some details at:

- https://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Messages_Selection.txt
- https://imapsync.lamiral.info/README

Comment: Thank you @Gilles. I will check out IMAP sync. It's open question and I'm not expecting imapsync to do all the magic. 
Other questions clearly put are:
1. Center users a restricted to the local email server, while some users can do both offline (local server) and online (remote server).
2. Users on the local server should be able send email out the local server (i.e. outgoing email.)
I hope that's provided more information.
Thanks for the help.